# Erro ao instalar adonisJS

Tags: javascript, react, adonisjs

Olá estou tentando instalar o adonis mas está dando erro (já rodei com o comando sudo npm i -g @adonisjs/cli):

```
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@adonisjs/cli/node_modules/fsevents/build'
gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.5.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@adonisjs/cli/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v72-darwin-x64/fse.node" "--module_name=fse" "--module_path=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@adonisjs/cli/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v72-darwin-x64" "--napi_version=4" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v72"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@adonisjs/cli/node_modules/fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v12.2.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@adonisjs/cli/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v72-darwin-x64/fse.node --module_name=fse --module_path=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@adonisjs/cli/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v72-darwin-x64 --napi_version=4 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v72' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@adonisjs/cli/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:196:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1011:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:268:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.5.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@adonisjs/cli/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@adonisjs/cli/node_modules/fsevents
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v12.2.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.12.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok 
Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@adonisjs/cli/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v72-darwin-x64/fse.node --module_name=fse --module_path=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@adonisjs/cli/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v72-darwin-x64 --napi_version=4 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v72' (1)
```

Comment: Qual é o seu sistema operacional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O seu problema está na **segunda linha**, onde diz o seguinte:

```
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@adonisjs/cli/node_modules/fsevents/build'
```

Como você não informou o seu sistema operacional, irei mostrar como resolver o problema de permissão de uma forma geral...

Se você observar um erro do tipo `EACCES` ao tentar instalar um pacote globalmente , você poderá fazer o seguinte:

- **1)** Reinstale o `npm` com um gerenciador de versões do nó (recomendado),
- **2)** Alterar manualmente o diretório padrão do `npm`

**Reinstalar npm com um gerente de versão de nó**

> Esta é a melhor maneira de evitar problemas de permissões. Para reinstalar o `npm` com um gerenciador de versões do nó, siga as etapas em [“Fazendo o download e instalando o Node.js e o npm ”](https://docs.npmjs.com/downloading-and-installing-node-js-and-npm). Você não precisa remover sua versão atual do `npm` ou do `Node.js` antes de instalar um gerenciador de versões do nó.

**Alterar manualmente diretório padrão do** `npm`

> **NOTA:** **Esta seção não se aplica ao Microsoft Windows.**
>
> Para minimizar a chance de erros de permissão, você pode configurar o `npm` para usar um diretório diferente. Neste exemplo, você criará e usará o diretório oculto em seu diretório pessoal. Vamos lá?
>
> - **1)** Faça o backup do seu computador.
> - **2)** Na linha de comando, em seu diretório inicial, crie um diretório para instalações globais: `mkdir ~/.npm-global`
> - **3)** Configure o npm para usar o novo caminho do diretório: `npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'`
> - **4)** Em seu editor de texto preferido, abra ou crie um `~/.profilearquivo` e adicione esta linha: `export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH`
> - **5)** Na linha de comando, atualize as variáveis ​​do seu sistema: `source ~/.profile`
> - **6)** Para testar sua nova configuração, instale um pacote globalmente sem usar sudo: `npm install -g jshint`
>
> **OBS:** Em vez dos passos 2-4, você pode usar a variável `ENV` correspondente (por exemplo, se você não quiser modificar `~/.profile`): `NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX=~/.npm-global`

**Outra alternativa é utilizar o** `NPX` **(uma alternativa para executar comandos globais)**

> Se você estiver usando o `npm` versão 5.2 ou superior, você pode considerar o [npx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npx) como uma maneira alternativa de executar comandos globais, especialmente se você precisar apenas de um comando ocasionalmente. Para mais informações, consulte este [artigo sobre o npx](https://medium.com/@maybekatz/introducing-npx-an-npm-package-runner-55f7d4bd282b).

[FONTE OFICIAL: DOCUMENTAÇÃO NPMJS](https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally)

Answer (score 1):

Eu consegui resolver com o seguinte comando.

```
sudo npm install -g @adonisjs/cli --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root
```